# Install pdf2htmlEX on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pdf2htmlex

I used this Aptfile:

```
fonts-liberation
libreoffice-base-core
libreoffice-calc
libreoffice-writer
libreoffice
libpython2.7
pdf2htmlex
poppler-utils
```

And installation completed successfully. I even checked version of pdf2htmlEX in heroku bash.

```
pdf2htmlEX --version
pdf2htmlEX version 0.14.6
Copyright 2012-2015 Lu Wang <coolwanglu@gmail.com> and other contributors
Libraries: 
  poppler 0.41.0
  libfontforge 20120731
Default data-dir: /usr/share/pdf2htmlEX
Supported image format: png jpg
```

But when I try to convert real PDF documents I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot open the manifest file
```

I found on other sites that I need to run "make install" to fix this issue but not sure if it's possible with heroku.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63115553/1848832) on pdf2htmlEX

On **heroki-18** I faced similar issue and resolved it by passing `data-dir` while converting.

If you are ruby you can use [Kristin](https://github.com/ricn/kristin) gem with *master* branch

Answer (score 0):

look at this:

> https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/issues/749

you just need to add the optional parameter `--data-dir C:\<pdf2htmlex-folder>\data` 
to the command